# PHP Google Analytics API Authorization error

Tags: php, rest, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I want to fetch Google Analytics data for my website via Google Analytics API.
First, I went to developers console, I enabled Analytics API, then under credentials section I created new ClientID (Service account).

Now, this is my code

```
include "assets/src/templates/base.php";

require_once 'assets/src/Google/autoload.php';

$client_id = 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //Client ID
$service_account_name = 'yyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com'; //Email Address
$key_file_location = 'zzz/key.p12'; //key.p12

echo pageHeader("Service Account Access");
if (strpos($client_id, "googleusercontent") == false
    || !strlen($service_account_name)
    || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
  echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
  exit;
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("app");
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);


if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();


$result = $service->data_ga->get(
       'ga:AAA',
       '2015-03-03',
       '2015-03-03',
       'ga:sessions');

?>
```

where AAA is my ViewID.
So, my problem is this: When I access this script on server it says

> *"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A91249839&start-date=2015-03-03&end-date=2015-03-03&metrics=ga%3Asessions:
>   (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\src\Google\Http\REST.php:110 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\src\Google\Http\REST.php(62): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>
> Object(Google_Client)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(174):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\src\Google\Http\REST.php(46):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\src\Google\Client.php(590):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(231):
>   Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Htt in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 110"*

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
golobich

*Edit: I've tried Google Books api and auth is working ok. (I've changed that link in $cred ofcourse.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key error is this:

> (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account

You are logging in with a service account.    You need to grant the service account access to your Google analytics account.

Solution:

Go to the google analytics website.  On the admin section add a new user using the service account email address, at the **ACCOUNT LEVEL** it must be the **ACCOUNT LEVEL** give this new user read access only that's all it really needs.

Then try your script again.